# How to use one method object with another method in Java?

Tags: java, swing, class, object, methods

I am beginning to learn Java and one thing is confusing me.

I have created a class PMO where I have created a TextField and put some text in it.
I have created another class PublicMethodObject where I have created the JFrame.

Now, I want to add the text set in TextField by using JFrame that I created in PublicMethodObject class.

How can this be possible?

```
class PMO{

public void J2(JTextField f1){

    JTextField f= new JTextField();
    f.setVisible(true);
    String s="Hellow World";
    f.setText(s);
    return f;

}
}

public class PassMethodObject {

    public PassMethodObject() {
         JFrame a=new JFrame();
         a.setVisible(true);


}


public static void main(String[] args) {


}

}
```

Comment: Wrong approach. You seem to have about 1% knowledge about basic Java, and 2% about Swing UI. Now you try to pull that together and get something useful out of it. Wrong approach. Nothing working will come out of that. Seriously: A) learn about java basics **first**. Really understand how things come together then B) read a good book/tutorial on Swing. You can't learn GUI programming by "trial and error" - that stuff is way too complicated. You need to know what you are doing. Thus, my serious answer: Stop now. Then start reading here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ - top to bottom.

Comment: Take a look at this website: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html. A couple hints: you will need to change the return type of your J2 function, and you will have to call that function from the constructor of PassMethodObject. If you have any more issues just add a follow-up comment.

Comment: And: read about java naming conventions. Use names that mean something. PMO means .. nothing. J2 means ... nothing. And: method names go camelCase. If at all, that method could be called `createTextField()`. But as said: your code implies that you have *no* idea what you are doing. So - throw it away and study the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty confusing.

Maybe you meant using one class's method in another class because that is what it seems you are trying to do. 
To do that you simply have to create the *object* of the first class inside second class and then use it for accessing the member variable and field(methods) of the first class. Unless it is static in that case you can call it directly using class's name.

example:-

```
access modifier Class A {

access modifier return type method(){};
}

access modifier Class B{

A ob = new A();
ob.method();
}
```

And of course, you have to take account of the access modifiers (public,protected,private,default) as well.

Comment: This is what how it is done in basic java(using one class's method with another class's method). I don't understand if you are in the beginning of learn java why are you doing swing?